# Call JSON on Spinner OnItemSelected and display data into another Spinner

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I am making an android app in which I am using two spinners. In first spinner I am displaying data from JSON which I've done successfully. Now by clicking an item of first spinner I need to display data from another JSON service into second spinner.

**First Service (I am displaying `city_name` from this service on first spinner):**

```
{"result":{"data":[{"city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},
{"city_id":"23","city_name":"B\u00e5stad"},
{"city_id":"22","city_name":"Halmstad"},
{"city_id":"19","city_name":"H\u00f6gan\u00e4s"},{"city_id":"20","city_name":"Helsingborg"},
{"city_id":"15","city_name":"Klippan"},
{"city_id":"24","city_name":"Kungsbacka"},
{"city_id":"21","city_name":"Laholm"},{"city_id":"18","city_name":"Landskrona"}],
"status":"true","description":""}}
```

**Second Service:**

```
{"result":{"data":[{"category_id":"18","category":"Aff\u00e4rsverksamhet",
"city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},{"category_id":"19","category":"\u00d6vrigt",
"city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},{"category_id":"13","category":"Bostad",
"city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},{"category_id":"15","category":"Elektronik",
"city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},{"category_id":"12","category":"F\u00f6r hemmet","city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},{"category_id":"11","category":"Fordon",
"city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"},
{"category_id":"16","category":"Fritid & Hobby",
    "city_id":"16","city_name":"\u00c4ngelholm"}],
    "status":"true","description":""}}
```

As you can see in both services `city_id` and `city_name` are common fields. If I select `city_name` from first spinner it will match through `city_id` or `city_name` and display `category` against that `city_name`.

Below is my code I have tried.

```
 private class AllCities extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url of First Service");

                HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

                String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                return new JSONObject(response);

            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if(result != null)
            {
                myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                if(! result.has("false"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject object = result.getJSONObject("result");


                        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");

                        stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
                        {   
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("city_id", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("city_id"));                            
                            map.put("city_name", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("city_name"));
                            myList.add(map);

                            stringArray.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("city_name"));


                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PostAdds.this, 
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner_city.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

            else if(result == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(PostAdds.this, 
                        "Hittade inga Detaljer Vänligen Kontrollera din Internet-anslutning", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {   
        //what am I suppose to do here????

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {


    }
```

Comment: What you are exactly looking for? Either to populate the second spinner or applying the filter from json in second spinner?

Comment: @kamil I want to Populate second `spinner` (by clicking an item of first `spinner`) and display `category` (from second `service`). Only those categories should be displayed in second `spinner` whose `city_id` or `city_name` will be matched. As I mentioned in the question both `services city_id` and `city_name` is common attribute.

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan did you solve this problem ? i really need the solution if you did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the late answer. I was solved this by my self but never came back here to post the solution which worked for me. Now I am posting this answer if any one has same kind of problem can get help from here.

So What I did

**1)** Call the first service and populate city names on first spinner and when item is selected of first spinner, save its value in a global String like

`String selectedCity;
selectedCity = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();`

**2)** When click any item of first spinner call the second service and put a simple check while populating the second spinner.

```
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
           JSONObject object = result.getJSONObject("result");
           JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");

           for(int a = 0; a < array.length(); a++) {
                 String cityName = array.getJSONObject(a).getString("city_name");
                if(cityName.equals(selectedCity)) // this check is important
                {
                        categories.add(cityName );
                }
          }
         // after for loop ends populate adapter of second spinner 
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);
         spinner2.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In this way I got my desired result. There are other solutions of this problem as well like one of them is when you call second service pass city_id or city_name along with url as params and service will only return you the desired categories.

Hope this will solve for any one has similar kind of problem. I just check my `Stackoverflow` profile today and found this question has not answered by any one so I did it my self :)